# Windows 8 Hyper-v - enable networking and remote connection

Tags: hyper-v, vhd

I have a vhd file, I need to enable networking and remote connection on it. On the vhd is installed Windows Server 2008 R2 and SharePoint development platform, VS 2010 ...

My laptop runs Windows 8 x64 Hyper-v. I can run the vhd into the hyper-v and works great, no problem. But I have no idea about hyper-v configuration and settings.

I want to desktop remote connect (from Windows 8) to the vhd file running Windows Server 2008 R2 (domain contoso.com) but I don't know how to configure the hyper-v to allow the network connection ... if I start the remote desktop connect on my Windows 8 and type the server name or domain\server ... it doen't work.

Any idea how to configure the hyper-v so I can have internet access in the VHD and connect to it using remote desktop connection?

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing you are using a Wi-Fi connection on your laptop. Hyper-V does not automatically use wi-fi connections, since it's a server technology and all.

But there are ways - here's an article from a MS dude explaining how to use a switch to bridge your wi-fi.

http://blog.credera.com/topic/technology-solutions/microsoft-solutions/using-your-windows-8-wireless-connection-inside-hyper-v/